# Override test dependency used in Activity.oncreate

Tags: koin

I have splash activity which checks for rooted device in onCreate(). Mocking the rootChecker does not work. It looks like loadingModule in activity is causing it. I don't want to load it in application as it will keep it in memory unnecessarily. How it can be fixed?

```
object SplashModule{
    var module= module{
        single { RootBeer(getAppContext()) }
    }
}

class SplashActivity : KoinComponent {
    @VisibleForTesting
    val rootChecker:RootBeer by lazy { get<RootBeer>() }
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        loadKoinModules(SplashModule.module)
        if(rootChecker.isRooted) {
            //show error and finish
        }
    }
}
```

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class SplashActivityTest : KoinTest {

    @JvmField
    @Rule
    val activityTestRule = IntentsTestRule(SplashActivity::class.java, false, false)

    @get:Rule
    val mockProvider = MockProviderRule.create { clazz ->
        Mockito.mock(clazz.java)
    }

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        stopKoin()
        startKoin { loadKoinModules(arrayListOf(TestModule().applicationModule, module)) }
    }

    @After
    fun after() {
        unregisterIdlingResource()
        stopKoin()
    }
    val module= module(override = true){
        single { Mockito.mock(RootBeer(getAppContext())::class.java) }
    }

    @Test
    fun testNonRooted() {
        declareMock<RootBeer> {
            given(isRooted).willReturn(false)
        }
        val launchedActivity = activityTestRule.launchActivity(Intent())
        //test here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to declare a mock provider for koin. Koin on its own doesn't know how to mock things when using `declareMock`. You have to tell to koin *how* you want to mock your objects, in your case with Mockito's `mock` function:

```
    @get:Rule
    val mockProvider = MockProviderRule.create { clazz ->
        Mockito.mock(clazz.java)
    }
```

and the following should not be needed anymore:

```
    val module= module(override = true){
        single { Mockito.mock(RootBeer(getAppContext())::class.java) }
    }
```

Comment: I did not add MockProviderRule.create block earlier as I thought it wasn't required. It is added in the question. Module declaration will be required, otherwise while testing real instance of Rootbeer will be used not the mock.

Comment: I think you would need to get RootBeer with `by inject()`